# Sectioned UITtableView with rows and columns

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I need to display some images(dynamic count) in `UITableView` acting like GridView.I want to show `3 images in each section`.

If it is >3 then it should follow the next section. All images are in `NSMutableArray(arr)` each image at one index.

Now suppose if there are 2 images then they should go into first section.If there are >3 (second section).Number of images in array are dynamic.

If 3 images are completed in each section then it should go into the next one.But I am not getting how to add into sections and if 3 images are filled then go to next section.

Here is the Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       static NSString *hlCellID=@"hlCellID";

        UITableViewCell* hlcell=[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];

        if(hlcell == nil)
        {
            hlcell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:hlCellID]autorelease];

            hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        int n=[array count];//dynamic item count (suppose 2)


        int i=0,i1=0;
        while(i<n)
        {
            int yy= 4+i1*34;
            int j=0;
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(i>=n)break;
                CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0+150*j,yy,150,40);
                NSMutableDictionary *d =[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [productsarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]autorelease];
                NSString* yourBase64String = [d objectForKey: @"image"];
                UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
                [myImageView setFrame:rect];
                [myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];

                NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:yourBase64String];
                UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

               NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i];
                myImageView.tag = [tagValue intValue];
                myImageView.image = image;
                [hlcell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
                [myImageView release];

                i++;




            }
            i1=i1+1;
        }

        return hlcell;

}
```

But here 2 images are added 1st in one section & other in other section (One below the other).

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Only 2 and 3 condition ? or may be more than that means dynamic sections ?

Comment: Yes dynamic number of sections ,but 3 items(images ) in each section.I have all the images in one NSMutableArray with each image at one index.Now I m not understanding how to take 3 images per section and displaying them..

Answer (score 2):

I have another idea and according to me it's simpler than you had implemented.

You have array of images. So what you can do is create a new NSArray containing NSDictionary like below :

```
(
    {
         headerTitle:@"first";
         imageDict:{
                       img1:@"abc.png";
                       img2:@"abc.png";
                       img3:@"abc.png";
                   }
    },
    {
         headerTitle:@"second";
         imageDict:{
                       img1:@"abc.png";
                       img2:@"abc.png";
                       img3:@"abc.png";
                   }
    }
)
```

Create this type of structure for Array.

Then implement table view delegate and datasource methods such as :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [array count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:section];
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];

    // Write code for header section

    return headerView;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      // display images if the available.
      // means if only 2 images are their then add only two and like-wise
}
```

I think this will help you. 
Thanks.